# Showing a space is homeomorphic to the quotient space of $X$ obtained by identifying $A$ to a single point.

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem:** If $X$ is any space, $A$ is a subset of $X$, and $p\notin X$, the space $X+_f\{p\}$ resulting from the function $f$ which takes $A$ to $\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space of $X$ obtained by identifying $A$ to a single point.

I've finished the section over quotient topologies, in Willards text, and came across this problem. Willard calls such constrictions "attachings". But, I really am not sure do such a problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll try to point you in the right direction.

Let $Y=X\cup\{p\}$, and define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $Y$ by letting $y\sim y$ for all $y\in Y$, $x\sim p$ for all $x\in A$, and $x\sim y$ for all $x,y\in A$; then $X+_f\{p\}$ is the quotient space $Y/\!\sim$. You want to show that this is homeomorphic to the quotient space $X/\!\approx$, where $\approx$ is the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by letting $x\approx x$ for all $x\in X$ and $x\approx y$ for all $x,y\in A$.

If $x\in X\setminus A$, $\{x\}$ is both a $\sim$-equivalence class and a $\approx$-equivalence class, and each equivalence relation has one other equivalence class: for $\sim$ it is $A\cup\{p\}$, and for $\approx$ it is $A$. It is therefore very natural to try to prove that the following map is a homeomorphism:

$$h:X+_f\{p\}\to X/\!\approx:[z]_\sim\mapsto\begin{cases}
[z]_\approx,&\text{if }z\in X\setminus A\\
A,&\text{if }z=A\cup\{p\}\,.
\end{cases}$$

In other words, both spaces look like $X\setminus A$ plus one extra point, and that point sits inside the space the same way that $A$ sits inside $X$: an open nbhd of the extra point in either quotient space looks like an open nbhd of $A$ in $X$, but with $A$ squashed to a single point.

Comment: This was very helpful and cleared up a lot!

Comment: @D.Math: Glad it helped!

Comment: I'm curious, though, is this problem of any use to do the following: Given $X=[0,1]$, $Y=[2,3]$, $A=\{0,1\}$, and let $f\colon A\to Y$ be defined by $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=3$. Then $X+_fY$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: @D.Math: Not directly, but you can use some of the same ideas: basically you just have to show that the two ‘identification points’ have the open nbhds that they ‘should’ have in order for the quotient to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: I semi-follow that, though still the concept is not *100%*. I think the concreteness of that problem would help me understand this stuff better, so I'll write it up as a new question. Perhaps you cold explain it in more detail there!